# How to write the syntax in lingo for the following objective function

Tags: linear-programming, lingo

I have this model which i want to run on Lingo, iam having hard time how to input this into lingo,
its a linear programming model btw

∑∑∑aik×ijk-∑∑∑wik×yijk